# How to install specific jdk/jre version in macos

Tags: java, intellij-idea, java-11, azul-zulu

How to install specific jdk/jre version in macos. I would need to install `11.0.7`.

I installed 11 version from here https://www.azul.com/downloads/?version=java-11-download-lts&os=macos#zulu but it ended up on version `11.0.18`. Also I don't find articles to download specific minor version `11.0.7`. Any suggestions?

Comment: Use `jenv`? https://github.com/jenv/jenv.

Comment: Why would you want 11.0.7 rather than 11.0.18? The third number indicates a release for bug fixes and security improvements, without changes to features.

Comment: If you *really* need an outmoded minor update version, check the archives of some JDK vendors. For example, [Adoptium](https://adoptium.net/) has archives, but their version 11 only goes back to 11.0.12. Besides Azul and Adoptium, other JDK vendors include: Microsoft, Amazon, BellSoft, SAP, Oracle, IBM, Red Hat, and more.

Answer (score 0):

You can download older updates of the Zulu builds of OpenJDK from our content delivery server:

https://cdn.azul.com/zulu/bin/

As others have pointed out, the use of older updates is not recommended due to the number of security vulnerabilities that you will be exposed to.